# What is the type of a styled-component's argument(s)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Using typescript and react here.

1. Getting my variable

`const dib = 'display: inline-block;'`

2. Creating a dumb component

`export const FaGit = () => <i className="fa-brands fa-github"></i>`

3. Extending this dumb component with `dib` styles

`export const GitIcon = styled(FaGit)(dib)`

4. At this point im getting errs

```
 TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray): StyledComponent<() => Element, any, {}, never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemeProps<any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<ThemeProps<any>>[]): StyledComponent<...>', 
gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemeProps<any>>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<{} & object, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<{} & object, any>>'.
```

And so, what the type of dib should be, or how should it look like?

Answer (score 2):

The `styled(SomeComp)(...)` function does not take a `string`. It takes a `TemplateStringsArray`. While this might look like a string, it's actually quite different.

See this [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgWwA4BsCGqAUAbjliCgM4BciAKutnigMpQBOMYA5uQIKus4AngBpEAOgkBrFIKqIcYQQG0AugEpEAbwBQiRBATk4WFGKxxO+KIIwo4wRMVIVRTsuVHTZa7QF9t2gZg5FCIACYwAEaIALyIAOQR5AyC1BxYHCgAtJHmEJIA3PGBhqERkQBMsYgABkkpaWAZYNm5cPkFNQGomLgE5T49DP1RFYP0fSg1ABYoWOaIACSaAIy+iADucKxYYV1DkzXL5b41QA) to see how such a tempate function might work:

```js
function template(values: TemplateStringsArray, ...keys: any[]) {
  console.log(typeof values, values, keys)
}

const dib = 'display: inline-block;'  // <= string
const dib2 = `display: inline-block;` // <= still a string

template(dib)              // error... function does not take a string
template(dib2)             // still an error
template`hello ${1} world` // working! this isn't a string, it's a tagged template
template`${dib}`           // how you might get your string into a s-c template
```

As an aside, the [styled-components documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components) gives the following advice regarding the styling of React components:

> If you use the styled(MyComponent) notation and MyComponent does not render the passed-in className prop, then no styles will be applied. To avoid this issue, make sure your component attaches the passed-in className to a DOM node

...so unless you pass down `className:string` property to the HTML element, your `FaGit` component will not respond to styled-components.

You could do it like this:

```
export const FaGit: React.FC<{className?: string}> = 
  ({className}) => <i className={`fa-brands fa-github ${className ?? ''}`}></i>
```

Putting this altogether, you should be able to:

```js
export const GitIcon = styled(FaGit)`${dib}`;
```